# Redirecting *.html to *.php, giving me public_html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've found plenty of resources for redirecting *.html to *.php with .htaccess and they all give solutions similar to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L, R]
```

I've tried various versions I've found and they all do the same thing. Instead of just changing the .html in http://example.com/examplepage.html to .php, for example, they redirect to http://example.com/home/example/public_html/examplepage.php

I honestly have very little idea what I'm doing with .htaccess, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a forward slash to `$1`, as below:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1.php [L, R]
```

Alternatively, set a `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteBase /
```